# How to I code Depth First Search without recurrence

Tags: python, depth-first-search

How to implement Depth First Search code in python without recurrence.
I have done it by class and recurrence method.
the following is by recurrence method:

```
graph1 = {
'A' : ['B','C','F'],
'B' : ['A','C','D','E','H'],
'C' : ['A','B','G'],
'D' : ['B','G'],
'E' : ['B'],
'F' : ['A','H'],
'G' : ['C','D'],
'H' : ['B','F']
}
count = []
def dfs(graph,node):
    if node not in count:
        count.append(node)
        for n in graph[node]:
            dfs(graph,n)
dfs(graph1,'A')
print(count)
```

The following is by class method:

```
class graph:
def __init__(self):
    self.dic = {}
def add_node(self,a):
    self.dic[a] = []
def add_edge(self,x,y):
    self.dic[x].append(y)
    self.dic[y].append(x)
def to(self):
    return self.dic
g = graph()
x = int(input('NO of nodes:  '))
y = int(input('NO of edges:  '))
for i in range(x):
    p = input('node:  ')
    g.add_node(p)
for i in range(y):
    o,p = input('edges between 2 nodes:  ').split()
    g.add_edge(o,p)
l = input('starting point:  ')
x = set()
def dfs(visited , graph, node):
    if node not in visited:
        print(node, end = ' ')
        visited.add(node)
        for new in graph[node]:
            dfs(visited, graph ,new)
dfs(x,g.to(),l)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "recurrence"?

Comment: I mean that in the codes above I am recalling the functions so like it is running the function over and over but I now I don't want to do it. I want to the function to run only once and give the desired output.

Comment: Ah, you mean *recursion*. Then Michael guessed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Basically by explicitly managing a stack instead of using the function call stack. Based on your first variant, function `dfs` will look like:

```
def dfs(graph,node):
    stack = [node]
    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        if node not in count:
            count.append(node)
            # To make it process items in same order as original code, order to stack must be reversed
            stack.extend(graph[node][::-1])
```